# using order_by() seperate from query

Tags: python, django, sorting, logic

I am retrieving some Posts using order_by in my for loop as given below

```
logged_user = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
followings = logged_user.follows.all()
all_posts = []
for foll in followings:
        all_posts += Posts.objects.all().filter(user_profile=foll.id).order_by('trending_ratio')
```

It sorts the Posts for each user, but I want to sort all post based on their `trending ratio`. for e.g the above code sorts all posts of user1 based on their `tending_ratio`, then it sorts posts user2 based on `trending_ratio` and so on.

But, I simply want to perform sorting after all the posts from all users is stored in all_posts i.e
`all_posts.order_by('trending_ratio')` after my for loop execution

Note : 
1. I follows a `ManyToMany` field in Posts model. 
2. followings is the list of all the users whom logged user follows 
models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trending_ratio = models.FloatField(default=1)
    ...
```

Comment: What is `followings`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman checkout edits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the posts in one query:

```
all_posts = Posts.objects.filter(user_profile__in=followings).order_by('trending_ratio')
```

This will order them correctly, as well as being much more efficient.